# How to make a GIF from a set of MATLAB images

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have an array of values which I turn into a color image like so:

```
my_img = imagesc(my_data(:,:,tidx)); axis off; colormap('default'); c=colorbar; c.FontSize=26; c.FontWeight='bold';
```

I want to know if it's possible to loop through all the index values in `my_data` and turn them into a GIF.

I tried this:

```
for tidx = 5:64
    my_img = imagesc(my_data(:,:,tidx)); axis off; colormap('default'); c=colorbar; c.FontSize=26; c.FontWeight='bold';
    imwrite (my_img, int2str(tidx)+"_cspattern.png");
end
```

Which gave me this error:

```
Error using imwrite (line 427)
Expected DATA to be one of these types:

numeric, logical

Instead its type was matlab.graphics.primitive.Image.
```

I looked it up and tried [this solution](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/523421-instead-its-type-was-matlab-graphics-primitive-image) out:

```
for tidx = 5:64
    my_img = imagesc(my_data(:,:,tidx)); axis off; colormap('default'); c=colorbar; c.FontSize=26; c.FontWeight='bold';
    IMG_to_write = uint8(normalize(my_img, 'range', [0 255]));
    imwrite(IMG_to_write, int2str(tidx)+"_cspattern.png");
end
```

But that just gave me this error:

```
Error using normalize>checkSupportedArray (line 159)
Invalid data type. First argument must be a real numeric or logical array, a table or a timetable.

Error in normalize (line 86)
    checkSupportedArray(A,method,methodType,false);

Error in GenerateFigures (line 18)
    IMG_to_write = uint8(normalize(SavePattern, 'range', [0 255]));
```

I feel as if I am overthinking this because there must be a simple way to load the data I want and save it as an image or series of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imagesc` produces a graphics object, not a data array. It’s meant for displaying images into figures, not saving them into files.  You need to hand `imwrite` your image data directly, along with your desired color map.

```
for tidx = 5:64
    imwrite(my_data(:,:,tidx),parula(),int2str(tidx)+"_cspattern.png");
end
```

If you want to scale each image so that the full color range is used, the way `imagesc` does, you can do this manually.

```
for tidx = 5:64
    my_data_slice = double(my_data(:,:,tidx));
    my_data_slice = my_data_slice - min(my_data_slice,[],'all');
    my_data_slice = my_data_slice / max(my_data_slice,[],'all')*255;
    my_data_slice = uint8(my_data_slice);

    imwrite(my_data_slice,parula(),int2str(tidx)+"_cspattern.png");
end
```